# In the field of db the value is zero output empty

Tags: c#, mysql

I work in ASP.NET 4 in C# and MySQL database.

In table, **doTable** I have the field **pcs** with data type **int length 11**.

I need to update this field **pcs** in a form.

The possible value in this field **pcs** are: **0, > 0 or null.**

But after I update the field **pcs** with **zero**,  why this field is still empty ?

In db, I have zero in field **pcs** and I think the problem is in the aspx page.

I have tried this without success.

Can you suggest?

Thank you in advance.

```
pcsDB = dr["pcs"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dr["pcs"]);

if (pcsDB > 0) {
          pcs.Text = pcsDB.ToString();
          pcs.Enabled = false;
} else {
          pcs.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pcsDB = dr["pcs"] == DBNull.Value ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(dr["pcs"]);
 if (pcsDB >= 0)
 {
  pcs.Text = pcsDB.ToString();
  pcs.Enabled = false;
 }
 else
 {
  pcs.Enabled = true;
 }
```